# The complex conjugate of a complex function.

Tags: complex-numbers

Hi I'm trying to work out the complex conjugate of:
$Ae^{(-a(mx+it))}$. 
Generally when I have tried to work out a complex conjugate of a complex number I just replace $i$ with $-i$. However I didn't know if it would work this time due to this being a complex function of two variables ($x$ and$ t$ who are real). When I do this and multiply the complex conjugate with the complex function I get a purely real answer which makes me think I'm right but like I said I've never done it like this before.

Also if this is right then is this what I can do with every complex function (replace $i$ with $-i$)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you are right. let $z=A\exp(-amx-ait)$ then $\bar{z}=A\exp(-amx+ait)$ providing $A$ is real of course. The real answer you refer to when you find $z \bar{z}$ is just the square of the modulus of $z$.

Comment: Yes you are correct. That is the complex conjugate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, I assume that $A = a = 1$. In general, for real $t$,
$$
\overline{e^{it}} = \overline{\cos t + i\sin t} = \cos t - i\sin t = \cos(-t) + i\sin(-t) = e^{-it}.
$$
Hence, for your expression you get
$$
\overline{e^{mx+it}} = \overline{e^{mx}e^{it}} = e^{mx}e^{-it} = e^{mx-it}.
$$
Hope this helps for understanding. If something is unclear, do not hesitate to ask in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\overline{r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))}=r\cos(\theta)-ir\sin(\theta)=r(\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta)).$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/883777)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: that's clearly tagged as a hint. It is actually very close to a complete solution, and I have made it even closer.